# Request/response conversation using UDPConn

Tags: network-programming, udp, go

I'm trying to implement the following UDP protocol, but I'm having a little trouble figuring exactly how I should approach this.

The protocol states that I should send a particular UDP packet to a certain server, after which the server will *stream* (several UDP packets that are related) a response back to me, also as UDP packets. I have managed to send the UDP packet fine using the following code:

```
connection, error := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, endpoint)
...
if written, error := connection.Write(query.ToBytes()); error != nil {
    ...
} else {
    log.Printf("Successfully wrote %d bytes to %s", written, connection.RemoteAddr())
}
```

When I use Wireshark and take a look at what's going over the wire, it looks like it sent the packet just fine (the only issue here is that I never get a reply from the server, but that's unrelated to this question).

What's the best way for me to handle the server reply in this case? Can I use the previously established `connection` to read server responses back (this seems unlikely to me, as it's UDP so connectionless) or should I use `net.ListenUDP(...)` to establish a server on the correct local address and port to read whatever the server sends back to me?

Comment: In the meantime, I've discovered the great [Network Programming using the Go Programming Language](http://jan.newmarch.name/golang) by Jan Newmarch. Seems like a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The intent of the protocol is clearly that you just use the same UDP socket to receive the reply that you used to send the request. If you have a client-side firewall, you will have to explicitly open a UDP port and bind the UDP socket to that port before you send. Otherwise just let the system choose the local port, by not binding at all.

The phrase 'the same port as was established by the intial packet' is misleading. Are they your words, or the protocol specification's? What really happens when you do the first send is that if you haven't bound the socket yet, it is automatically bound to a system-chosen port, exactly as if you had bound it to port zero.

Comment: Those are my words, and they were meant to clarify that I was under the impression that I couldn't choose the client port myself *before* issuing the first request. However, in the meantime I've managed to figure it out and that proved to be a misunderstanding on my part. Right now I've got a working version of the code that does as you suggest; not bind at all and let the system choose.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the specific protocol design, it's impossible to know on which port the server will send its reply packets. After taking a second look at the packet dumps, I noticed that the server in fact *does* reply, only the client immediately replies back with an ICMP message saying `Destination port unreachable`. So the server was trying to reply, but it couldn't because the client would not accept the packets on that port.

To solve this, I have used `net.ListenUDP` to listen for incoming packets immediately after the client sends the initial packet using the established connection's local address:

```
incomingConnection, _ := net.ListenUDP("udp", connection.LocalAddr().(*net.UDPAddr))
log.Printf("Listening for packets on %s", incomingConnection.LocalAddr())
defer incomingConnection.Close()
```

After which `incomingConnection` can be used as a `Reader` - for example - read the packets that the server is sending.